# Divide the sum of grades using pivot operator

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql, sql-server-ce

```
SELECT
    Student, [English], [Mathematics], [Science], [Programming], [History]
FROM
    (SELECT Student, Grades, Subject 
     FROM Grade_Report) AS SOURCETABLE
PIVOT
    (SUM(Grades) 
        FOR Subject IN ([English], [Mathematics], [Science], [Programming], [History])
    ) AS PIVOTTABLE
```

Output:

```
Jamie   188.00  161.00  163.00  183.00  184.00
Jenny   175.00  173.00  174.00  172.00  172.00
Jerome  184.00  186.00  184.00  191.00  181.00
```

Expected output:

```
Jamie   94      80.50   81.50   91.50   92
Jenny   87.50   86.50   87      86      86
Jerome  92      93      92      95.50   90.50
```

Comment: Rather than SUM() in the PIVOT perhaps try AVG()

Comment: How can i apply that in my codes?

Comment: Change `SUM` to `AVG` where you're currently using `SUM`. It's in exactly one spot in your current SQL, so you should be able to figure it out.

Comment: In your PIVOT, you currently have Sum(Grades)   ...  change it to Avg(Grades)

Comment: You need to show the input data (ideally as DDL+DML) that produces those results.

Comment: can you show what is input table?

Comment: CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Grade_Report](
 [Student] [varchar](50) NULL,
 [Subject] [varchar](50) NULL,
 [Grades] [numeric](18, 2) NULL,
 [Semester] [int] NULL
);

Comment: i change the sum to avg but its still not working

Comment: Dale K i dont get want your saying. sorry

Comment: may be use `SUM(Grades) / 2`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each student may have two marks in each subject?
Make sure of that first of all

Try to use the average **AVG(Grades)**

```
SELECT
Student, [English], [Mathematics], [Science], [Programming], [History]
FROM
(SELECT Student, Grades, Subject 
 FROM Grade_Report) AS SOURCETABLE
PIVOT
(AVG(Grades) 
    FOR Subject IN ([English], [Mathematics], [Science], [Programming], 
 [History])
)
```